# Running aidl service in background?

Tags: android, service, aidl, android-service-binding, bindservice

I have a aidl process through which i make connection to my server and perform login, But the problem is when i close the application i am unbinding the service in `onDestroy()` callback of activity, so here my server connection gets disconnected and i need to connect every time when i launch my application (while binding service in `onCreate` of activity).

I want my service to run even if user exits the application or kill the application, so that user will not require to connect to server every time launching the application and get a seamless experience.

Can i achieve this by implementing `onStartCommandRecive()` in service and returning `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from callback function

Comment: so you need both started and bound service, more [hiere](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: basically i need to persist the server connection even if the component bound to service unbinds the service, so that user don't need to connect and login every time

Comment: so you need both started and bound service

Comment: can i achieve this in aidl ?

Comment: i gave you a link above, did you read it?

Comment: yes , i read it , but didn't find any proper solution to the problem.